# Will any type of solder bond to any non-conductive material?

Tags: soldering, conductivity

Are there materials which solder will physically bond to but itself is not electrically conductive?

Comment: I have had frequent moderate success with regular 60/40 solder on denim. Flux content does not appear to be an issue.

Comment: Let's not forget dermis (like one ever could... *shudder*).

Comment: Glass, for example. With the right soldering iron. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpJ8T8JWMMw

Comment: ah i missed these replys. Denim, ha! Jonathan S, thanks for that video. its exactly how i would like my soldering iron to be behaving but alas is not. i shall look into these curious devices!

Answer (score 4):

"bond" is a strong word (pun intended).

So, the excellent bonding properties of let's say solder-copper are basically because solder partially migrates ("solves") into the structure of the metal (and the other way around), so that you basically get interwoven/interlocking crystals.

That will only work with metals. Metals conduct.

So, the next best thing is gluing behaviour. And that can already be pretty strong between any heat-resistant, smooth surface and solder. You'd need very clean surfaces, and something to make the surface creep work for you. It seems (thanks, Jonathan!) that ultrasound can help with that :)

Another option is actually going the more destructive road: If trying to solder something onto a thermoplastic plastic part, then that part will simply melt around the piece, and that can be an excellent plastic weld. Superior quality welds between metal and plastic is, however, usually achieved through ultrasonic punctual heating (see: joghurt lid made from aluminium).

Then, it really depends on what you need to achieve, but:

You could also use one of the chemical deposition methods used to coat non-conductors (plastic, ceramics) in copper (and often, after that, ultimately in chrome) and plainly solder to that.

Maybe, also a polished surface of a plastic with copper pieces embedded would have enough copper surface for mechanical bonding, but due to a lack of touching copper, no conductivity.

Comment: +1. I think you mean "ultrasonic" (> 20 kHz) rather than "supersonic" (> Mach 1).

Comment: err yeah. indeed. *he says, getting out of his fighter jet*

Comment: I just tried cleaning some glass with isoproyl alcohol and it did work but no particularly well. i used tin/lead solder with flux. do you think it would work better without the flux or another type of solder or indeed if you could recommend another substrate? thanks so much for that very informative reply!

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. Flux, in general, sounds good, because it makes solder distribute more evenly on surfaces. Experiment with preheating the glass, using less or more flux, different solder. If you want it done right, I guess the device from Jonathan's video looks great.

Comment: @MarcusMuller You're breaking charater again! You're supposed to be all wörk wörk and no funny jokes.

Comment: @winny yeah, I know. I'll have to fill out all the unlicensed humor paperwork *again*. And that really annoys me, because as much as I love bureaucracy, it stops me from doing work.

Answer (score 0):

Thick film hybrid circuits use ceramic substrates with fired-in-place
metallizations.   It is possible (with the right solders) to solder
to those metallized surfaces.

Direct 'solder' to insulator bonding is unlikely, because the word
'solder' is defined as a low-melting material that joins metals.